# Using mmap memory for a circular buffer with very low overhead

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have a debugging tool which in order to register its acquired data uses a data structure called `DiskPool` (code follows). At start, this data structure `mmap`s a certain amount of data (backed by a file on disk). Clients can allocate memory via a simple bump pointer mechanism (implemented using `std::atomic<size_t>`.

As the volume of acquired data is massive I have decided to have a window over a time period instead of registering and keeping all the data. To fulfil such a purpose I have to change the disk pool into a circular buffer but this should not impose a considerable overhead as this overhead affects the measurement.

I wanted to ask you if anybody has any idea? (For example, using an atomic interface of STL).

```cpp
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <atomic>
#include <memory>
#include <signal.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

#define handle_error(msg) \
        do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

class DiskPool {
    char* addr_;        // Initialized by mmap()
    size_t len_;            // Given by the user as many as memory pages as needed
    std::atomic<size_t> top_;   // Offset from address_
    int fd_;
public:
    DiskPool(size_t l, const char* file) : len_(l), top_(0),fd_(-1)
    {
        struct stat st;
        fd_= open(file, O_CREAT|O_RDWR, S_IREAD | S_IWRITE);
            if (fd_ == -1)
                    handle_error("open");
            if (ftruncate(fd_, len_* sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)) != 0)
                handle_error("ftruncate() error");
            else {
                fstat(fd_, &st);
                printf("the file has %ld bytes\n", (long) st.st_size);
            }
            addr_ = static_cast<char*>( mmap(NULL, (len_* sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)),
                    PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_NORESERVE, fd_,0));
            if (addr_ == MAP_FAILED)
                    handle_error("mmap failed.");
    }
    ~DiskPool()
    {
         close(fd_);
         if( munmap(addr_, len_)< 0) {
             handle_error("Could not unmap file");
                        exit(1);}
            std::cout << "Successfully unmapped the file. " << std::endl;
    }
    void* allocate(size_t s)
    {
        size_t t = std::atomic_fetch_add(&top_, s);
        return addr_+t;
    }
    void flush() {madvise(addr_, len_, MADV_DONTNEED);}
};
```

As an example, I created sample code that uses this disk pool to record data at the creation and destruction of an object (`AutomaticLifetimeCollector`).

```cpp
static const std::string RECORD_FILE = "Data.txt";
static const size_t DISK_POOL_NUMBER_OF_PAGES = 10000;
static std::shared_ptr<DiskPool> diskPool =
    std::shared_ptr <DiskPool> (new DiskPool(DISK_POOL_NUMBER_OF_PAGES,RECORD_FILE.c_str())); 

struct TaskRecord 
{
    uint64_t tid;   // Thread id
    uint64_t tag;   // User-given identifier (“f1”)
    uint64_t start_time;    // nanoseconds
    uint64_t stop_time;
    uint64_t cpu_time;
    TaskRecord(int depth, size_t tag, uint64_t start_time) :
        tid(pthread_self()), tag(tag),
        start_time(start_time), stop_time(0), cpu_time(0) {}
};

class AutomaticLifetimeCollector 
{
    TaskRecord* record_;
    public:
    AutomaticLifetimeCollector(size_t tag) :
        record_(new(diskPool->allocate(sizeof(TaskRecord)))
                TaskRecord(2, tag, (uint64_t)1000000004L))
    {
    }
    ~AutomaticLifetimeCollector() {
        record_->stop_time = (uint64_t)1000000000L;
        record_->cpu_time = (uint64_t)1000000002L;
    }
};

inline void DelayMilSec(unsigned int pduration)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_until(std::chrono::system_clock::now() + 
            std::chrono::milliseconds(pduration));
}

std::atomic<bool> LoopsRunFlag {true};

void sigIntHappened(int signal)
{
    std::cout<< "Application was terminated.";
    LoopsRunFlag.store(false, std::memory_order_release);
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGINT, sigIntHappened);
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while(LoopsRunFlag)
    {
        AutomaticLifetimeCollector alc(i++);
        DelayMilSec(2);
    }
    diskPool->flush();
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: What are you actually storing? Do you just want the last N `TaskRecord` to be saved? How is a client to know that their `allocate` is now invalid and they should not read/write it anymore?

Comment: Here actually most of the recorded data is substituted with constant values for simplicity. But mostly they are timestamps. reading is not important. reading will be done later with another graphical program. exactly I want to have a window that records a defined number of records in circular mode. when reaching to the mmap dedicated memory start from the beginning.

Comment: OK, so different sizes, that could be trick;y. `t = std::atomic_fetch_add(&top_, s) % len_` might work, but need to think through what happens if `top_` overflows. Otherwise you probably need more than just an `atomic_fetch_add`, I suspect there are better solutions than a mutex though.... Either way `len_` needs to be big enough that it will never wrap around before some client is done writing. Also when your "graphical program" reads it, needs some thought to be correct without using a mutex to stop stuff changing while it reads.

Comment: In Addition to the problem of top_  overflow  that you mentioned correctly, I am not sure if % operator is the most efficient and lowest possible overhead here. For example I was looking for a solution using atomic interfaces of STL like CAS. len_ is massive.

Comment: An integer `%` operation is really cheap in the overall scheme. You could probably do a `read, add-and-wrap, cas` loop to get safe overflow, but that doesn't guarantee safety of slow writes, or provide a safe mechanism to read the data later.

Comment: This debugger works until very rare happening problem occurs and then the graphical program comes and open the file and visualize the information. So the old data is not of importance. The problem is very rare and could not happen for months. That is the reason that a window should be used otherwise the volume of acquired data will be massive. And _len is massive enough till the next round nobody is using that address anymore. Could you please provide me with a sample with CAS or add-and-wrap? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So accounting only for the handing out of variable-sized slices for a variable buffer, I believe a Compare-And-Swap loop should work.

The basic idea here is to read a value (which is atomic), do some computation with it, then write the value, *if it did not change* since reading. If it did change (another thread/process), the computation must be redone with the new value.

Since you have variable sized objects, I think actually simply slicing it into n array elements with `(i + 1) % n` won't work, as given `(i + item_len) % capacity`, it would split the allocation between the end and start of the buffer, and while that can be correct and working, I think maybe not what you wanted. So that means a condition, but I think the CPU should predict it pretty well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<size_t> next_index = 0;
const size_t len = 100; // small for demo purpose
size_t alloc(size_t required_size)
{
    if (required_size > len) std::terminate(); // do something, would cause a buffer overflow
    size_t i, ret_index, new_index;
    i = next_index.load();
    do
    {
        auto space = len - i;
        ret_index = required_size <= space ? i : 0; // Wrap if needed
        new_index = ret_index + required_size;
    } while (next_index.compare_exchange_weak(i, new_index)); // succeed if value did of i not change
    return ret_index;
}
int main()
{
    std::cout << alloc(4) << std::endl;  // 0 - 3
    std::cout << alloc(8) << std::endl;  // 4 - 11
    std::cout << alloc(32) << std::endl; // 12 - 43
    std::cout << alloc(32) << std::endl; // 44 - 75
    std::cout << alloc(32) << std::endl; // 0 - 31 (76 - 107 would overflow)
    std::cout << alloc(32) << std::endl; // 32 - 63
    std::cout << alloc(32) << std::endl; // 64 - 95
    std::cout << alloc(32) << std::endl; // 0 - 31 (96 - 127 would overflow)
}
```

Which should be fairly simple to plug in to your class:

```
void* allocate(size_t s)
{
    if (s > len_ * sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)) std::terminate(); // do something, would cause a buffer overflow
    size_t i, ret_index, new_index;
    i = top_.load();
    do
    {
        auto space = len_ * sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE) - i;
        ret_index = s <= space ? i : 0; // Wrap if needed
        new_index = ret_index + s;
    } while (top_.compare_exchange_weak(i, new_index)); // succeed if value did of i not change
    return addr_+ ret_index;
}
```

`len_ * sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)` is in a few places, so might be the more useful value to store in `len_` itself.